# Interfacing with MySQL Database via HTTP

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm working on a project that involves linking my C# application to a MySQL server. The server is running cPanel and the company does not allow all IPs to connect to it (although you can add host IPs to the remote list). The application will be running on Windows 8 Tablets on a 3G connection, so obviously I will not know the IPs if the devices to be able to add them to the list.

A collogue of mine has told me of a system, API or something like that that will allow me to interface with the Database via HTTP effectively bypassing this restriction.

I can provide more information if needed.

Does anyone know of anything similar to this or any way around this?

Comment: Didn't that colleague mean _"Write a web service that talks to the database and let your app talk to the web service"_?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySql 5.7 or higher, there is an experimental "lab" for allowing direct access to MySQL via a REST over HTTP interface, eliminating the need for a middle-tier server or database specific drivers.

You can download [the plugin](http://labs.mysql.com/) at the MySql Labs site. From the dropdown, select "MySQL HTTP Plugin" and you should be good.

Keep in mind that its part of the "MySql Labs" project, which means its experimental, probably buggy and should be used at your own risk. Think twice before using them on any kind of production server.